# How to remove empty lines from an updated XML?

Tags: java, xml, dom

So what I'm doing is, I'm finding and deleting some tags from an XML. After deleting, those tags are getting replaced by blank space, which actually ain't effecting the XML but it can cause problem when I delete a large number of tags.

Any working way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

[Here is the link of the answer I found here but it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669686/how-to-remove-extra-empty-lines-from-xml-file)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner file;
    PrintWriter writer;

    try {

        file = new Scanner(new File("src/myXml.xml"));
        writer = new PrintWriter("src/myXml2.xml");

        while (file.hasNext()) {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.write("\n");
            }
        }

        file.close();
        writer.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Comment: But it didn't work for XML. I guess, XML follows something else for this.