# How to remove empty line while reading a file

Tags: java, readfile, filewriter

I would like know how I can remove a blank line while reading/writing a file?

```
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++) {
    FileInputStream fistream1;
    try {
        name1="file1"+Integer.toString(i)+".txt";
        fistream1 = new FileInputStream(name1); // first source file
        fistream2 = new FileInputStream("Result.txt");  //second source file
        sistream = new SequenceInputStream(fistream2, fistream1);  
        fostream= new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( result+".txt", true)));

        while( ( temp = sistream.read() ) != -1) {
            fostream.write(temp);   // to write to file
        }

        fostream.println("");
        fostream.close();
        sistream.close();
        fistream1.close();
        fistream2.close();
}
```

I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190639/remove-all-blank-spaces-and-empty-lines) but I couldn't implement it because of following line:

```
String line;
while((line = br.readLine())!= null) { ... }
```

They have used `line` as a `String`, but in my case I have `temp` as `int`:

```
int temp;
while((temp = sistream.read())!=-1) { ... }
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

The answer of @Abdelhak is not acceptable.

Comment: "but couldn't implement it"... what problems did you have with the code in the accepted answer?

Comment: the problem is `temp`, because of `int`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
while( ( temp = sistream.read() ) != -1) {
  if (!temp.trim().equals(""))
  {
    fostream.write(temp); // to write to file
  }
...
```

Comment: Except that _temp_ will be an int .

Answer (score 0):

The solution was so simple.

I should read lines instead of reading bytes to determine if a line is empty and used a BufferedReader on conjunction with SequenceInputStream.