# Removing blank spaces from CSV with java

Tags: java, regex, string, csv

Before leaving a negative comment about me copying questions:
I've read the other stackoverflow question ([Remove all blank spaces and empty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190639/remove-all-blank-spaces-and-empty-lines)) about this and tried out all of the suggestions but none worked for me.
I want to remove blank spaces in the following CSV:

```
<STX> somevalue;somevalue1;somevalue2 <CR><LF>
```

I need to remove the blank space between "STX" and "somevalue" and the blank space between "somevalue2" and "CR".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a regex to replace only the space(s) after `<STX>` and before `<CR><LF>` but I let you write it, there are plenty of post about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace:

```
String s1="<STX> somevalue;somevalue1;somevalue2 <CR><LF>";
String replaceString=s1.replace(' ','');//replaces all occurrences of ' ' to ''
```

Comment: This is only works if `somevalue#` don't have spaces

Comment: Using replace does work with  astring, that's true, but my file is a .CSV. This was my first idea too, but I did not find a solution to convert a CSV to a String in java yet.

Comment: @AxelH it's guaranteed that somevalue_n does not have any spaces.

Comment: @timor, A csv is only a text file with a specific delimited character. So read the file, there is API for this. SO the question is `How to read a CSV?`. Also, specifiy that the are no space any other place then

Comment: @timor https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<STX> somevalue;somevalue1;somevalue2 <CR><LF>";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: use replaceAll() instead of replace()

Comment: Same problem I talked about at Nikos Vita Topiko's answer.